# Webcam not "detected" - Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, webcam

I have a usb microsoft livecam nx-3000 webcam connected to an ubuntu 12.04 laptop. (lsusb: Bus 001 Device 003: ID 045e:0721 Microsoft Corp. LifeCam NX-3000 (UVC-compliant))

Under windows 7 and ununtu 13.04 works fine. In ubuntu 12.04 I get cheese: no device found, but in sound I can choose webcams microphone.

Any solutions? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got mine working as follows in (13.10):

Open up the terminal an do the following:

```
echo 'options uvcvideo quirks=0x100' | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/uvcvideo.conf
```

See: [www.linux-hardware-guide.com](http://www.linux-hardware-guide.com/2013-10-16-microsoft-lifecam-nx-3000-usb-webcam)